# Creating a private image in LXD

Tags: lxc, lxd

I am confused because the command to create an image from a snapshot is called `lxd publish`. Does it create a publicly available image? How can I create a private image. I want an image with ssh keys, api tokens etc inside, so obviously it must be private. I thought maybe I could just launch a new instance specifying another instance or a snapshot, but I get `Error: not found`.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you can create new containers from other containers, or rather from snapshots of other containers like this:

```
lxc snapshot my-container my-snapshot
lxc copy my-container/my-snapshot my-new-container
```

You do not need to `launch`, `copy` will launch it as far as I can see.